# Parsing datetime from email in Python 2.6

Tags: python, email, datetime, imap, python-2.6

Hello i have issues parsing a date from an email with Python 2.6
Here's the code :

```
    typ_sent, data_sent = sentbox.fetch(num_sent, '(RFC822)')
    mail_sent = email.message_from_string(data_sent[0][1])
    subject_sent = unicode(email.header.decode_header(mail_sent['Subject'])[0])
    from_sent = unicode(email.header.decode_header(mail_sent['From'])[0])
    datetime_sent = email.utils.mktime_tz(email.utils.parsedate_tz((mail_sent["Date"])))
    datetime_sent = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(datetime_sent)
```

I have an error when trying to have the date time from the mail in the datetime object. Here's the message error.

```
File "checkIMAP_client.py", line 116, in <module>
    datetime_sent = email.utils.mktime_tz(email.utils.parsedate_tz((mail_sent["Date"])))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/email/_parseaddr.py", line 142, in mktime_tz
    if data[9] is None:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

And i'll need to parse a datetime object to a valid email date format.

EDIT :
In my script i need to compare emails from the sent items and inbox folders.
I can read the date from the inbox emails (i use the append command on an email.message() object)
But i can't read the datetime from the emails sent from my SMTP using smtplib.

I modified the code a bit to see what happens : 
Code :

```
datetime_sent = unicode(mail_sent["Date"])
print("Datetime sent =" + datetime_sent)
```

Prompt :

```
Datetime sent =None
```

I will look on how the Date is supposed to be implemented in the sent emails. It seems i have an issue here since the inbox mails haven't the issue.

EDIT :
Ok, i found the issue.
I'm sending emails from my server to a distant server with smtplib.
When the distant server recieves the mail from my server on a certain adress, it redirects it back to original adress.
My scripts can't read the datetime from the sent email.
So what is the right format i need to use for email.parsedate_tz() to work ?

Comment: Does the message have a valid `Date:` header? You have multiple function calls in one line; perhaps you can unroll them over several lines to see where exactly you get an unexpected result. Maybe [edit] your question to include these diagnostics. See also the guidance for including a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you targetting Python 2.6 in this day and age? Transitioning to 3.6 would get you a much updated `email` library with built-in date parsing.

Comment: Comment 1 : 
I had a bad Date format on some emails i was parsing. After a purge on the test mailbox it was OK. I was afraid to have an issue because of other Stack people having the same issue.
Comment 2 : 
I can't update Python on the server that will execute the script.

Comment: Maybe undelete and accept your anwer so as to make it clear that this is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
So i checked my parsing functions.
It works when i send a mail from Thunderbird using my smtp server.
I can get my datetime object.
Stuff hit the fan when i'm sending my mail with python.